# Multiple Linear Regression Analysis in QGIS (with SAGA Toolbox)

Tags: qgis, saga, regression

I'm attempting to run a multiple linear regression analysis using QGIS, through the SAGA toolbox.

However, the QGIS UI does not allow me to choose predictors -- it seems entirely absent from the UI. Is this a bug, or am I mis-understanding something?

I am running QGIS 2.18.15, with SAGA 2.3.1 under Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: From the first look it seems to me, that you would choose the predictors as coefficients in the UI. Could you try that with your data?

Comment: How does the simple Linear regression work in QGIS? I am wondering if I am missing something or just the implementation is different. I am used t